# Bootstrap4 compiled css and js file

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap compiled css and js in my project. when I include the css file it comes with `_reboot.scss` file even though it does not exists in the path. How to compile the scss file into single css file?

Answer (score 0):

_reboot.scss is a Sass partial file. If you wanted to compile it into a single css file, there are a couple different options depending on your environment. I recommend visiting the [Sass documentation page](https://sass-lang.com/install) for more information.

Comment: How to download bootstrap only the compiled css file

Comment: Solved I complied using sass https://www.mugo.ca/Blog/How-to-customize-Bootstrap-4-using-Sass